# Geometry program doesn't work on iPad Mini 2 iOS 9

Tags: ios, shader, scenekit

I can't run my program with shaders on node's geometry in iOS 9. Here is test code:

```
import SceneKit

class Test: NSObject, SCNProgramDelegate {

    private static let SIZE = 10

    private static let RES = 256

    var node: SCNNode!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        setup()
    }

    func program(program: SCNProgram, handleError error: NSError) {
        NSLog("program error: %@", error)
    }

    private func setup() {
        node = SCNNode()
        node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, -Float(M_PI) / 2)

        node.geometry = createGeometry()
    }

    private func createGeometry() -> SCNGeometry {
        let size = CGFloat(GpuHeightFieldWater.SIZE)
        let geometry = SCNPlane(width: size, height: size)
        geometry.widthSegmentCount = GpuHeightFieldWater.RES
        geometry.heightSegmentCount = GpuHeightFieldWater.RES

        let program = SCNProgram()
        program.delegate = self
        program.vertexShader = loadShader("test.vsh")
        program.fragmentShader = loadShader("test.fsh")

        program.setSemantic(SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex, forSymbol: "a_position", options: nil)
        program.setSemantic(SCNModelViewProjectionTransform, forSymbol: "u_mvpMatrix", options: nil)

        geometry.program = program

        return geometry
    }

    private func loadShader(name: String) -> String! {
        let file = NSString(string: name)
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(file.stringByDeletingPathExtension, withExtension: file.pathExtension)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        return String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}
```

test.vsh:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 a = a_position;
    a.x = 0;

    gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix * a;
}
```

test.fsh:

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Node added to root node of scene and I see plane (with strange purple color) but my program never runs and I don't see any errors for my program. So it looks like my program ignored.

What is wrong and how to run program for geometry right?

Update #1

When I ran app on iPhone 5s simulator it printed error about my vertex shader code at line 7.

> ERROR: 0:7: Incompatible types (float and int) in assignment (and no
>   available implicit conversion)

When I fix that error, it works. Strange that when I run this app on my iPad Mini 2 (iOS 9.0) I don't see any errors.

Update #2

To avoid misunderstanding I changed question title because I found that on iPhone 5s simulator it shows program error. So problem is related to iPad Mini 2 with iOS 9.

Also I noticed that on my device it shows Metal (Mt):

[image]

and on iPhone simulator it shows GL:

[image]

Maybe it is related to issue somehow.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was in `Rendering API` parameter for `SCNView` view. When you create project from `Game` template it has `Default` rendering API.

Looks like default means `Metal` and that was a reason why my program for geometry was ignored. When I changed Rendering API to `Open GL ES` it started to use my program with shaders.

When I run my app in simulator it uses `OpenGL ES` as default rendering API. I don't know why it works this way because it is confusing developer. Enumeration has only two values:

```
enum SCNRenderingAPI : UInt {
    case Metal
    case OpenGLES2
}
```

No any `Default` value and how developer will guess what iOS selects as rendering API? I'm not happy with this part of documentation.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I think this is a big part of a problem that stems from Storyboards and the big three game engines GUIs being the inspiration for Scene Editor and Particle Editor. And them being incomplete and undocumented. There's more than a few things slightly different between how they're done in code and presented in the docs versus their presentation and options within the visual Editors that determine your states. And OpenGL and Metal don't render in the same manner on iPad mini 2. Try using additive blend mode with a few layers to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line 7:

```
    a.x = 0;
```

to

```
    a.x = 0.0;
```

The error is actually hinting at the line (`0:7`) and the problem, as you are giving a `int` where a `float` is expected.

Comment: I know how to fix error (see Update #1). My question is about why in iOS 9 it doesn't print any errors.

Comment: Interesting. Is any other kind of log/error showing? Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: No, it doesn't print anything when I run in on real device with iOS 9.

Comment: Hmm... It seems like more of an OS problem than SceneKit. Do you have any other iOS9 device nearby to try?

Comment: No, I have only one device with iOS 9 - iPad Mini 2.

Comment: I would suggest making a new empty app with just an NSLog. If you don't get that one, consider restoring your device.